# Pass column name and column value in a procedure that execute plsql query

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

In oracle PLSQL , how to pass a column name and column value to a procedure .
The procedure executes select command based on the where clause 
such that `Select * from FOO where columnname=columnnvalue`

and the procedure stores the resultset (refcursor) in a OUT parameter.

here columnname and columnvalue are passed by user

Comment: What have you tried?  You just specify input and output parameters in the declaration (doucmented at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/parameter_declaration.htm#LNPLS1271).  However, if it can be any column - of any data type - you'd have to decare its input parm as a string then convert it inside the proc.

Comment: Oh I got it `str := 'select h.* from holidaymaster h where ' || column_name || '=''' || column_val || '''';
open ref_cursor for str;  
` it works will varchar2, date and number so far .

Comment: **Why the 2 downvotes ??**

Comment: When the downvoters don't leave a comment we will never know. But maybe the reason is because this is verry dangerous. Your code is a great example of how to get sql injected.

Answer (score 1):

> As i can see you have not shared any inputs. I have tried to replicate
>   scenario as per your requirements. Please check below snippet. Hope it
>   helps

```
set serveroutput on;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE USER_INPUT_PROC(
    p_col_name_input IN VARCHAR2,
    p_col_val_input  IN VARCHAR2,
    p_lst_out OUT sys_refcursor )
AS
  lv_col VARCHAR2(10000 CHAR);
BEGIN
  NULL;
  SELECT DECODE(p_col_name_input,'empno',' AND EMPNO = '||''''||p_col_val_input||'''','ename',' AND ENAME = '||''''||p_col_val_input||'''','')
  INTO lv_col
  FROM DUAL;
  OPEN p_lst_out FOR 'SELECT * FROM EMP
WHERE 1 = 1 '||lv_col;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this safely you need to use the dbms_sql package. The coding becomes pretty involved.